# Outside component prop's change doesn't trigger componentDidUpdate (but triggers re-render)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my code below, I'm re-rendering user data-consuming components on the page whenever the data updates.

About the DialogModal component, re-rendering from outside currently outputs :

- [class'] render() is correctly executed with the new props
- **state is kept** (the *current* value at the previous *dialog* index)
- **componentDidUpdate isn't called**, & that's where the problem lies ..

I was first expecting :

- from an outside re-render, the component to be fully re-mounted

But I'm now trying to :

- use the componentDidUpdate feature to trigger the *current* value re-initialization

For an unknown reason, calling the outside render() method doesn't make me enter inside componentDidUpdate (even if it's correctly rendering, with the current *dialog*)

```
const updateUser = (updates, lang) => {
  const updatedUser = Object.assign({}, window.user, updates)
  window.user = updatedUser

  render(<UserPanel user={ window.user }/>, document.getElementById('anchor-user-panel'))

  const firstDialog = updatedUser.dialogs.find(dialog => dialog.openFirst)
  if (firstDialog) {
    render(<DialogModal dialog={ firstDialog }
        uid={ window.user.uid }
        updateUser={ updateUser }
        lang={ lang }
        translations={ window.translations.dialog }/>, document.getElementById('anchor-dialog'))
  }
}
```

Comment: Nevermind my previous comment, i just realized that `render` in that code is ReactDOM.render.

Comment: You say that `DialogModal` componentDidUpdate is not being called?

Comment: Yeah that's it. I don't understand why, I already used it before ..

Answer (score 0):

Rapid explanation and solutions :

- **componentDidMount** is called **after** the component re-render, which means that you must code a resilient render() mehtod (allowing a lifecycle with incoherent data)
- to fit my use case (setting state.current to 0 when the dialog prop was changed [from the outside]), you may use **getDerivedStateFromProps** .. even if [this React article](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html) strongly insists on the postulate that, "*you probably don't need derived state*"

. Take a dive in !